# what is the home directory of kettle(PDI) in ubuntu

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I just want to know where the Home Directory of Kettle(PDI) is in UBUNTU 14.04. I know in windows it is in the user & called kettle.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `.kettle` folder in the home directory.

If you are not able to find it, just do a <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, to see the hidden folders.

Answer (score 1):

In the home folder of your user (`~/.kettle`).

You can also set the variable `KETTLE_HOME` if you need it in another location.